# Isomorphic JavaScript with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, isomorphic-javascript

I have some isomorphic JavaScript. I am using RequireJS on the client side.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    function wrapper(require) {
      var MyDep = require('my-dependency');

      return function MyExportedFunction() {
          // ...
      };
    }

    if ((typeof exports === 'object') && module) {
        module.exports = wrapper(require); // CommonJS
    } else if ((typeof define === 'function') && define.amd) {
        define(function(require) {
            /**
             * I need to `require` dependencies 
             * in here for them to be available inside 
             * the wrapper function :(
             */
            require('my-dependency');
            return wrapper(require);
        }); // AMD
    }
}());
```

Is there a way to circumvent having to place the `require` statment positioned immediately before the `wrapper` function invocation?

If I omit that `require` statement, RequireJS complains that the dependency has not yet been loaded for the context.

I presume this is an insurmountable limitation of RequireJS' ability to parse and identify require'd dependencies ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, RequireJS can only handle the CommonJS form of `require` only if it is present immediately in the factory function passed to `define`. If it appears in functions called from the factory function but that are defined outside the function, then it won't work. Internally, RequireJS runs a regular expression on the factory function's source.

This being said, it seems to me you should be able to replace your current call to `define` with:

```
define(wrapper)
```

This will call `wrapper` with a reference to RequireJS' `require` function *and* RequireJS should be able to analyze the source of `wrapper` to extract the CommonJS calls.